# Pivot Activity Code Days Months

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the activity codes for specific days to show the 31 days in every month of the year for a specific staff member.

If the staff member was present, sick, holiday leave, etc... I want those activity codes to display based on the output below for a year act_date range.

Thanks!

[image]
[Pivot Activity Code Days Months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0eIb.png)

Comment: Could you please past what's in the image on the body of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with pivoting. Here you can enter the staff id in the query to fetch the results for that particular staff.

```
--create table
create table staff_info
(
staffId int,
actDate datetime,
activityCode int
)

--insert values
insert into staff_info values 
(2699, '01/02/2017', 101),
(2699, '05/14/2017', 303),
(2699, '08/06/2017', 101),
(1927, '10/25/2017', 105)

--actual solution
select * from 
(
select staffId, day(actDate) as act_day,month(actDate) as actual_month, 
activityCode
from staff_info
where staffId=2699 ----- enter the staff id here
) src

pivot

( 
sum(activityCode)
for act_day in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],
[14],[15],
[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
[31]
)
) p
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, I am getting an error message but I am not sure  how to post my image. I do not have create access currently with SQL Server currently. I am only able to select.  How can I post another image? Sorry this is my first post.

Comment: change the table and column names accordingly... dont run the query directly...I created the table only for the test purpose

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a function which would give the date values for a specific range

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllDatesBetweenRange]
(
   @FromDate DATE
   ,@ToDate DATE

)
RETURNS @Dates TABLE
(
   DateVal DATE
)
AS
BEGIN

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT @FromDate AS FromDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,FromDate)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE FromDate < @ToDate
)

INSERT INTO @Dates
SELECT FromDate FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

RETURN;

END

GO
```

Use the below dynamic query to pivot for the specific date range

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DateVal NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DateVal = STUFF((SELECT ',['+CAST(DateVal AS NVARCHAR(50))+']'
FROM [dbo].[GetAllDatesBetweenRange]('2017-01-01','2017-12-31')
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql = '
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Res1.STAFF_ID
      ,Res2.DateVal
      ,Res1.ACTIVITY_CODE
FROM [dbo].[GetAllDatesBetweenRange](''''2017-01-01'''',''''2017-12-31'''') Res1
LEFT JOIN TableA A ON A.ACT_DATE = Res1.DateVal
)
SELECT STAFF_ID
       ,*
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ACTIVITY_CODE)
    FOR DateVal IN ('+@DateVal+')'+'
)'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql
```